# Laravel job dumps exec() error into command line instead of $output

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to build a simple deployer in Laravel, that will receive a webhook, perform a deployment and store some information (from the hook) about said deployment.

I am using Laravel 5.2 jobs dispatcher to perform the following:

```
public function deploy()
{
    $result = 0;
    $output = array();
    exec('cd ' . $this->deploymentMapping->full_file_path . '; git pull', $output, $result);
    return array(
        'result' => $result,
        'output' => $this->outputToString($output)
    );
}
```

My understanding of the `exec()` function is that this should not dump any errors directly, but will store them in `$output`.

However, when I run `php artisan queue:work` on my server in the command line, to test the job dispatcher, I just immediately get `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` dumped into the command line output. **This git error is correct**, but it is making the job "fail" as though `exec()` threw an error. Is this correct? My job should be reporting the error in its own way, as follows:

```
public function handle()
{
    $deploymentAttempt = new DeploymentAttempt();
    $deploymentAttempt->deployment_id = $this->deploymentID;
    $gitResponse = $this->deployer->deploy(); //the above function
    $deploymentAttempt->success = !($gitResponse['result'] > 0);
    $deploymentAttempt->message = $gitResponse['output'];
    $deploymentAttempt->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because PHP's `exec` doesn't provide a simple way to capture the `stderr` output separately.

You need to capture the `stderr` too.

Redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` should do the trick. Append `2>&1` to the end of your command.

```
exec('cd ' . $this->deploymentMapping->full_file_path . '; git pull 2>&1', $output, $result);
```

It will fill the array `$output` with the expected output, one line per array key.

To know more about how `2>&1` works you can follow [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/4816207)

Comment: Thanks! The error that was making the job fail wasn't actually this problem with StdOut/StdErr, it was actually me writing `$deploymentAttempt->success` rather than `$deploymentAttempt->successful`. I'm a dingus. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks man, this saved me hours of troubleshooting...